# unusual LDAP distinguishedName format

Tags: active-directory, ldap

encountered an unusual format for an active directory LDAP result, in a log created at a customer site - when LDAP querying active directory from a C#(.Net) app.
instead of strings in the usual format: "cn=group1,ou=someOU,dc=company,dc=com",
getting "cn=group1 ou=someOU dc=company dc=com" (no commas!)
googled till my fingers burn but can't find an explanation so far.
can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's very unlikely that the server returns such broken DNs. most likely that the software transforms it on the way to log file.

Comment: My first thoughts too - still researching this. however the software just dumps the result into a string and sends it over WCF. and anywhere else it arrives OK (with commas). will update if I unravel the mystery.

Comment: OK, I'll leave my question as a warning to other users :) indeed, the DB export tool was generating CSV, it replaced commas with whitespace. notice though, if you have an LDAP parser - make sure it can handle special characters encoded using slash - "," => "\,", ";" => "\;" etc- see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366101(v=vs.85).aspx